# AS3: Detect if camera is being used by other program

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

I tried looking on the net, but I can't find the solution.

I'm working on a Flash video recorder, and when loading the recorder on Chrome, if there's another browser is already using the camera, I'm unable to use the camera on chrome.

What I'd like to do is to tell the users that the camera is being used by another browser or program, and they need to stop the other program from using the camera in order for them to be able to use the recorder.

Comment: You add an error handler, so if you are to "get camera" and receive an error or null, just output that message.

Comment: @Vesper the camera is always not null and not muted. Seems like it's not an error, but Flash does not continue when other program is using it. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct - getCamera will always return the Camera object if the camera exists, even if it's being used by another application.  Others have recommended looking for output from the camera and saying it's not there after a period of time, but that's not very satisfying to me...